# Laravel - Project-Flyer: property of non-object after adding second flyer for user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Been following the project flyer series on laracasts and it seems I have an issue when creating a second flyer for a single user.

I can create a flyer and then display information upon the user who created the flyer by writing

```
{{ $flyer->owner->name }}
```

and this displays fine on the first flyer that I create with that user.

However, if I then try to create a second flyer with the same user, I get this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object...
```

dd() throws this on $flyer->owner on the second flyer:

```
null
```

but throws this on the first flyer:
[array of user information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ6fP.png)

It seems then that there is an issue with my relationships? But it seems strange how it works fine the first time, but adding a second flyer to a single account causes this error.

I can create multiple accounts all with one flyer each and it will work fine, but as soon as I add a second flyer to one account, it messes up.

I'm not sure if I have missed anything out from the videos, but non of them have been in the situation of creating more than one flyer per account so far.

## I have fixed this issue, please see below for my own answer.

Comment: what kind of relationship did you define between flyers and users?

Comment: in my user model, I have this: 
`return public function flyer(){ return $this->hasMany(flyer::class); }`
and this in my flyer model:
`public function owner(){ return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id'); }`

Comment: The first return is a typo? and in the `hasMany() ` why don't you use the same syntax as in `belongsTo()` like `hasMany('App\Flyer')`?

Comment: Yes sorry. My mistake.

I did notice that when I was going through the code, and I did test it out with ('App\Flyer') but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this issue myself.

In my flyer model, I was incorrectly referencing the foreign key. I was looking for the 'id', but I should of been looking for the 'user_id'.

So the correct code for the flyer model should be:

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

I found this out by searching github for a clone of project flyer to see if I could see anything different with my code. Turns out it was just this simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on relationships [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

I believe ( not really sure about that) that the reason it worked the first time is that you were creating some kind of [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with this static call.

Comment: Hm. It just seems strange as the relationships are set up the same as the relationship between a flyer and its photos, yet that seems to work fine.